# daily sunshine hours/ minutes from weather API

Tags: python, python-3.x, openweathermap, weather, meteostat

I am currently using `meteostat` weather API and extracting data, but I see that sunshine minutes is NaN for mostly all the countries. Am I doing something wrong? Should I look for a Paid weather API? my major focus is Sunshine minutes or hours per day for last 3 years.

I m using the below code snippet

```
!pip install meteostat

# Import Meteostat library and dependencies
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from meteostat import Stations, Daily

# Set time period
start = datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2022, 12, 31)

# Get daily data
data = Daily('06660', start, end)
data = data.fetch()

data
```

where 06660 is the weather station WMO code for Switzerland. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging in the `meteostat` documentation and issues on github. If you change the weather station from the one you're using to the one given in the documentation [example](https://dev.meteostat.net/python/daily.html#example), values of `tsun` aren't `NaN`. You are able to see proper data. So it's probably not an issue with your code but simple the `tsun` data for your weather station isn't available. In this [issue](https://github.com/meteostat/meteostat-python/issues/120) on their Githib [repo](https://github.com/meteostat/meteostat-python), the Founder of meteostat has [commented](https://github.com/meteostat/meteostat-python/issues/120#issuecomment-1451621240) saying

> Unfortunately, there isn't much we can do about it. tsun is one of the parameters which isn't well covered by most weather stations. We can only try to incorporate more data sources moving forward. But it might be the data simply isn't available for the weather stations in this area.

Comment: Thanks, yes - it's available for Germany but unfortunately not for other countries in Europe (France, Spain, Italy, Poland, Switzerland etc).  by any chance do you know if we can find sunshine hours via some other paid weather API? or the data is not available at all